# Spring OAuth2.0 : Authorization and Resource server in 1 Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The old `spring security oauth` can do this by `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure`

How can it be implemented using the latest spring security 5.7.x?

It seems that you have to create separate authorization server, resource server, and client...unlike the previous, you just have to enable configuration for authorization and resource server

But I am curious if there is  a way to do libe the old way?

Comment: did you find anything ?

Comment: I post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I discover this on my own.

Both the authorization and resource server can be in 1 springboot app and both can use same port.

It is the security configuration filter chain that you have to restrict both the "/login", "/oauth2/authorize"

Authorization server configuration is configured the basic way and so is the Resource server.